# Sum analytical function or any other easy way

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below Data and need to select all columns with sum of one column

```
 id size desc1, desc2
 1   13   xxx   yyy
 1   13   xxx   yyy
 1   10   mmm   kkk
 1   10   mmm   kkk
```

I need below output

```
 id  **total_size** desc1 des2
 1    23         xxx   yyy
 1    23         xxx   yyy
 1    23         mmm   kkk
 1    23         mmm   kkk
```

total_size should be sum (distinct size)

Comment: What does "*distinct size*" mean?

Comment: sorry "size" is the column name

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id
    ,a.size
    ,sum(b.size) as 'total_size'
    ,a.desc1
    ,a.desc2
from (
        select *, row_number() over (order by id, size, desc1, desc2) as 'RowNumber'
        from #tmp
      ) a
    left join (
                select *, row_number() over(partition by id, size order by id) as 'dupe'
                from #tmp
               ) b
        on a.id = b.id
        and b.dupe=1
group by a.RowNumber
    ,a.id
    ,a.size
    ,a.desc1
    ,a.desc2
```

Not here to argue, but you should really consider reviewing the data structure you're working with.

1. Select your data, adding a column to number the rows
2. Join a copy of your data (with distinct records only)
3. Sum the size column from the list of distinct records

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `sum(distinct "size") over (partition by id)` for computing `total_size` column for each row in your [***`SQL`***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/86a4b/5) :

```
with tab(id,"size","desc1","desc2") as
(
 select 1 ,13,'xxx','yyy' from dual union all
 select 1 ,13,'xxx','yyy' from dual union all
 select 1 ,10,'mmm','kkk' from dual union all  
 select 1 ,10,'mmm','kkk' from dual
)
select t.id, 
       sum(distinct t."size") over (partition by id) as "total_size",
       t."desc1",t."desc2"
  from tab t;
```

P.S. `size` is a *reserved keyword*, **so**, *cannot be used as a column name, unless quoted.* as `"size"`